# How to improve my site's loading time?

Tags: performance

my wordpress site is hosted on godaddy, using flatsome theme, 7 plugin (including img-lazy load & woocomerce).
i have use free cloudflare cdn, 
but still my site need 13+ seconds to load.
i have checked it on gtmetrics, and it says i have too much DOM (4,5k+)

Comment: We don't provide site audits. Apart from that the question is way too broad when you don't tell us what you've tried yourself so far and where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: @leymannx In this case it's a matter of understanding how sessions can have an effect on performance. I think this is an important subject even if the question is not worded this way.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett – It always is important. And this may be an interesting riddle to be solved, indeed. But this question doesn't care about being a good question or showing any efforts of solving the issue on their own. It also doesn't care about our guidelines. That's why this question should be flagged instead of being answered hunting for rep. My opinion. Although I like your answer as it gives an interesting starting point for OP to hop on.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Woocommerce which starts a session for every visitor to your site. This limits Cloudflare's cache performance since each unique session needs to be handled individually. That's how things like the shopping cart work.

Woocommerce [added the ability to store this session data in object cache](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/6846) rather than the database (memcached/Redis/etc).

I'm not familiar with GoDaddy's hosting since I personally don't recommend that company, but they should have object cache storage of some sort available. It's just a matter of you configuring WordPress and Woocommerce to use this cache.

That should help things a bit.